# How to enable root on the Lion "Recovery" boot drive?

Tags: install, startup, recovery, root

There's a few funny things / clues *here and there* on the Lion recovery disk "Systems" - that indicate you *can* save your settings between boots. A very light smattering of persistent settings etc. Beyond that.. Does anyone know if you can **enable the root account** or if there is an admin password etc. on these boot drives? It would kinda be nice to be able to look around when booted to these things, possibly see what's going on under the hood etc..  Also, it might open the door to being able to SSH to the machine, which would definitely come in handy during tough installs, or other strange circumstances.

Comment: Let's keep this Lion for now. Feel free to mention MoLo once it hits general release (or the NDA is lifted).

Comment: The user of the Recovery boot drive is the root. So you need to rephrase your question to emphasize what is it you're after beside the "root" account. If I understand UNIX accounts correctly, and I don't claim I do, "root" is just another user that just happens to be a super-man of all users. You can do whatever you wish in the shell of the recovery mode.